# From PHP to ASP.net/C#?

Tags: c#, php, asp.net

I know this may seem like a common question on SO but I could not really find anything in particular to my exact question.

Just throwing some of my thoughts so far out there, PHP is super super easy and FAST to code in, I do not know C# or how to use ASP.net, I would like to learn it and studying some of it briefly it seems to me that it takes a lot more coding and time to code the same result in ASP.net

So I am just curious is there any noticable benefits of having for example a social network in ASP.net vs having it in PHP?  Not looking for a debate but I need some guidance

Hopefully this is not to broad of a question, I couldn't really put it into words exactly how I wanted at the moment

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I converted to ASP.NET C# around 2 years ago and never looked back!

I love C# and ASP.NET ...For me it just allows me to get on with things, eg a gridview control to render result from the database without me having to manually construct it via table tags.

ASP.NET also has the repeater control should you wish to retain complete control over the output.

My progression into ASP.NET would not of been as easy and straight forward if I didn't know PHP, PHP will always have a special place for me because it was my first web development language.

So yes, I would say go for it... the way you build pages in ASP.NET is vastly different compared to PHP so don't get too confused by it all.

Answer (score 4):

Anything you can do in C#/ASP.NET you can do in PHP and vice versa.

I would use the language that has the most support for the specific features you want your application to contain.

**EDIT:**

This also would mean to use the language that has the most support from the developers who will develop it.

Comment: thanks for the answer, that is what I was curious about, if it was more of a preference type thing or real benefits of 1 over the other in all cases

Comment: I personally find that ASP.NET creates more maintainable code. It also requires a slightly different perspective of interacting with the user/web through state management.

Answer (score 0):

PHP was a good language a few years ago. I don't know about PHP6, but PHP5 does not match out with the languages today, even scripting languages [like python]. I seriously suggest you should move on to C#/ASP [not necessarily .NET]. Be extremely vary of using the .NET framework. The abstraction layer it sets up does not really come out as well given the fact that you'll be working with the Web: a system that hasn't evolved quite systematically [take browser compatibility for example]. Although some may argue that such a framework will actually help out compatibility issues, Microsoft's stand [till now atleast] on the general 'open web' concept leaves many questions unanswered.

Answer (score 0):

If you decide to take a look at C#/ASP.NET, I strongly suggest considering the context for comparison. PHP is a scripting language, ASP.NET is a web application framework. A better comparison between the two would be to put ASP.NET side to side with something like Symphony or CakePHP.

Also, coming from the PHP world I think it's easier to get started with ASP.NET MVC, because there's less magic going on under the hood in that flavour. It's very similar to CakePHP/Symphony in essence. Also, you won't get annoyed with the shitty HTML output the older WebForms engine spits out ;-)

I think PHP is a fine language, but it tends to get a tangled old mess when the application grows. Sure, you can overcome that by strict discipline, but that takes focus off of the real job at hand. In C#, things are a lot more strict. Type safety is enforced (you cannot simply assign a floating point value to something that used to be a string, etc.), syntax errors turn up at compile time, opposed to at runtime in PHP.

TLDR:
I say give it a go, especially the ASP.NET MVC variant. If you don't like it, that's fine, there's loads of applications built in PHP that work like they're supposed to. The least thing you could get from it is a bit of understanding of how other environments work :)